# What should I do with pokemon or candies that I cannot use

Tags: pokemon-go

What should I do with Pokemon or candies that I cannot use to evolve, like Taurus?

Answer (score 12):

The only use for candies right now is to **evolve** pokemon and to **power them up**. Future generations will have more evolutions (for example Golbat, Zubat's first evolution has an second evolution in Gen2).

You can save them for that future evolutions (you can check those [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_with_cross-generational_evolutions)), but you can just use them to power up your pokemon with some stardust as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would say hold on to them, until Nintendo/Niantic releases Generation 2 Pokémon. I have some Scyther candy that I can't use, but I will be able to use them once they release *Scizor*, the evolved form of Scyther.

If you want, you can use them to power up your Pokémon, for example, Scyther or Taurus.

Comment: I think he's talking about candies on pokemon that doesn't have an evolution in next generations

Answer (score 1):

Keep the highest two or three CP Taurus and similar un-evolvable type mon you have. Free up storage space by transferring the rest to the professor.  There are no negatives to holding the unusable (for now) candies.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily use them as filler Pokemon for gym battles or adding them in gyms. They can also be used for training. :D